# delay a $link.text after a fade out (jquery)

Tags: jquery, delay, fadeout, slidetoggle

I want the second [read more] to appear after the `.content` fade out. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Mq3B/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <span class="heading">This is the beginning of the sentence. </span>
    <span class="content">This is the end of the sentence. </span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.heading {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.content').after('<a href="#" class="toggle-link">[Read More]</a>');
    $(".content").hide();
    $('.toggle-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this);

        if ($link.data('expanded') == true) {
            $link.data('expanded', false);
            $link.text('[Read More]');            
        } else {
            $link.data('expanded', true);
            $link.text('[Close]');
        }

        $link.prev(".content").fadeToggle(1000);
    });    

});
```

Comment: do the things you want to do after the fadeout completes.. inside a fadeout callback function... `...fadeToggle(1000,function({ //here });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add all your dispalying codes after the callback function of fadeToggle() , to make sure it completes..

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.content').after('<a href="#" class="toggle-link">[Read More]</a>');
$(".content").hide();
$('.toggle-link').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   var $link = $(this);
    $link.text('');  //<---here empty the text so the animation is clear
    $link.prev(".content").fadeToggle(1000,function(){



    if ($link.data('expanded') == true) {
        $link.data('expanded', false);
        $link.text('[Read More]');            
    } else {
        $link.data('expanded', true);
        $link.text('[Close]');
    }
    });
});    

});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/4Mq3B/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside the fadeToggle callback, so that it appears after the animation is completed. Plus if you are storing is Expanded just for swapping the text value you don't need it. You can instead use .text() callback function to return the value based on current text.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.content').after('<a href="#" class="toggle-link">[Read More]</a>');
    $(".content").hide();

    $('.toggle-link').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $link = $(this);
        $link.prev(".content").fadeToggle(1000, function () { //Do it here
            var isExpanded = $link.data('expanded'); //Get the expanded value
            $link.text(function (_, text) { //use .text() function to switch value
                return text == "[Read More]" ? "[Close]" : "[Read More]"; 
            });
            $link.data('expanded', !isExpanded); //Dont need this if you are using this only  for expand collapse text switching.

        });
    });

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f3cJv/)**

Comment: Thank you but I want the effect to apply only to the second read more (after I have click on close).

Comment: @Giom You dont want to do it on CLose?

Comment: Sorry I don't get your question.  With my code, when I click on read more for the first time, then a close link appear. Until there everything is ok. But then when I click on close, the read more link appear before the fade out effect. I would like to delay the fade in of this second read more so that it will appear after the fade out of the content. No sure if I am clear enough! Thank for your help!

Comment: My question is what heppned when you click on ReadMore close should appear before the fade animation is complete?

Answer (score 0):

```
How about
$link.prev(".content").fadeToggle(1000, function(){
    //code to fade read more link in
});
```